# angularjs - run controller on page load

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular code snippet.  I want to call the home page template on page load. How is this achieved? Also, currently my template is pre-populated with the text I want to display.  Is it better to pass data to the raw template using $scope and then display it.  Thanks.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider

.when('/', {
     templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
     controller  : 'homeController',
})
});

myApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
//$scope.message = 'welcome to the home page';
});
```

Update:  I think I may have found the problem. I also have an index.php file in my directory.  When I remove it appears to work as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here.  If you are routed to `/` then the controller will load fine.  What difficulties are you having?

Comment: This works fine if I click on a link <a href="#/">Home</a>.  I want to have the home page open when I go to my index.html file.

Comment: Thanks.  see my update

Answer (score 0):

try putting the directive ng-view your homepage, by example:

```
<html>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also you can see the example in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Answer (score 0):

As a sort of catch-all that should also cause your preferred page to show immediately, I'd suggest setting it with [`otherwise()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#otherwise) in `app.config()`.

In the config function:

```
$routeProvider

.when('/', {
     templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
     controller  : 'homeController',
})
.otherwise('/')
```

Admittedly, this may not work exactly how I expect, because it seems like you're using the default Angular-Router, while I'm working with [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).